# Passing arguments to Class constructor PHP SOAP?

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, constructor

I am trying to pass arguments to the class constructor, but have not been successful. I have tried the following

PHP

```
$c = "site.wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($c,array('classmap' => array('state' => "mystate",'county' =>  "mycounty")),array("trace"=> 1,"exceptions" => 1)); 

$client = new SoapClient($c,array('classmap' => array('state' => "mystate",'county' =>  "mycounty")));

$client = new SoapClient($c,array('state' => "mystate",'county'=>"mycounty"));
```

Webservice Code Java

```
@WebService
public class MyWebservice{
 String test =  "";

/**
 * 
 * @param county
 * @param state
 */
public MyWebservice(@WebParam(name = "county") String county,
            @WebParam(name = "state") String state) {   

    test= county+"_"+state;
            //want to use this String elsewhere in the class
}

}
```

Error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [S:Server] com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class
```

If I remove the parameters from the constructor  I do not have any issues creating the soap client.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

you're supposed to map to php classes (by providing a string with their name), which in turn are used to forward the parameters to the remote URI, I get the impression you're using classmap as a way to try and send parameters directly. If not maybe post your mycountry and mystate classes and your wsdl file.

You'll find a very detailed example of how to use SoapClient with classmap on this [blog post](http://pookey.co.uk/wordpress/archives/78-using-the-classmap-with-soap-in-php) (not mine) It's very clear and I would suggest you to read it over once to make sure this isn't the problem. Hope it helps. :)